# remove rows of dataframe based on difference with other dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 1000 observations that I have analysed using 4 different models. The results of these models are stored in 4 data frames, that look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

model_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={"observation_id": [0, 1, ..., 1000], 
                             "param_1": [0, 4, ..., 2]})

model_2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"observation_id": [0, 2, ..., 1000], 
                             "param_1": [1, 3, ..., 1]})
```

similarly for the other two (there are actually many more parameters in the data frames).

The "observation_id" uniquely matches the results of a model to the observation. So an observation_id of 0 gives the results of the four models for that particular observation.

The problem is that there are gaps in the modelled data. model_1 might be missing observation_id 45 and model_3 might be missing observation_id 721.

How can I create four new data frames containing just the results related to observation_ids that are common to all 4 datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `merge` with `how='left'`

```
from functools import reduce
p1 = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='observation_id',how='left'), [df1,df2,df3,df4])
```

If you only want one df not four

```
from functools import reduce
df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='observation_id',how='inner'), [df1,df2,df3,df4])
```

Comment: Your first one should be `how='inner'` or `how='outer'`.  `how='left'` constrains to the keys of `df1` which is not a complete set.  `how='outer'` would bring in the missing `observation_id` and fill with `Nan` and `how='inner'` would drop where keys are not common across all (which is what OP asked).  `how='left'` attaches importance to the `observation_id` in `df1` that it doesn't have.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I am confused by this ** four new data frames**

Comment: Fair enough.  I do realize that your second example is `how='inner'`.  I just don't see the utility of `how='left'` for OP's question.  It still delivers a single DataFrame and still shows the columns from all the DataFrames.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski still thank for looking into it :-)